# CSS hover two elements

Tags: css

I have these 3 divs:

[image]

The red one is absolute positioned.
I'm trying to change the border color when hovering.

The problem is that there is a precedence by the rendering order (which can be altered using z-index).
But I want to trigger the hover effect on all hovered elements.

In this example - I want the green area to trigger hover of both red and blue, and hovering the yellow area to trigger hover of purple and red.

When hovering the blue div that doesn't overlap, I want only the blue to be "hovered" (same goes for the red and purple divs)

Is that possible?

Comment: It is not possible, not without JavaScript. Unless you can make one of these divs a container, which would mean if you hover over any of the blue, you also hover over red, but that would include blue and green.

Comment: Its not possible from this way. you either have to use js and canvas and ... or consider having separate divs for each pear of your painting

Comment: Its not possible from this way. you either have to use js and canvas and ... or consider having separate divs for each pear of your painting

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with `:hover` and general sibling selector `~`.

> Note: If you want the hover to work for the overlapped area, you'd need to update order with z-index.

The solution:

If you have "blue", "red" and "purple" classes, you can update the borders based on `:hover` pseudo class and selecting its sibling like

```css
.blue:hover, .blue:hover ~ .red {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Full code for the solution is shared [here](https://codepen.io/PritamH2SO4/pen/poROzLd)

Comment: Thanks for the full answer! The missing part is the area that doesn't overlap. When hovering a non-overlap area - I want only the one element to be "hovered"

Comment: Not sure if you can do with css alone, you'll have to do add some JS I think.